# Python 3.4, Ubuntu компиляция файла в .exe без wine

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, компиляция, wine

Проект пишу и тестирую на Python3.4, Ubuntu.

На данный момент его уже можно использовать в работе на Windows машинах.

Как я понял PyInstaller используется для создания бинарных файлов, но поддержки кросс-платформенной компиляции нет. Для этого предлагается использовать Wine. Это несколько раздражает так как придется устанавливать все необходимые библиотеки по новой (параллельно). А именно из за этого я ушел в разработку на Ubuntu с Windows - тут проще поставить все необходимые библиотеки, без получения ошибок типа не хватает компилятора C++ 10.0.

Выглядит это все как полный костыль, и неудобство очевидно.

Существует ли элегантное решение данной проблемы? Скомпилировать .exe файл из под Ubuntu без Wine.

Comment: В виртуалке с виндой это повторить

Comment: Если честно не понял, чем поможет виртуальная машина. Проблема в том что это требует паралельной установки python и всех требуемых библиотек на Windows версию или в Python под Wine. Идеальное решение представляется какой то одной командой:
"python-compile-to-windows project.py project.exe" находясь в это время под Ubuntu/

Comment: @Amaroc возможно у вас неправильна исходная позиция. Вы хотите *компилировать* **исполняемый** код python. То, что он исполняемый, говорит о том, что предполагается, что на хосте будет установлено все окружение python. А компилируется (скорей, упаковывается) в исполняемые файлы то, что предполагается запускать на хостах без окружения. Поэтому, продукт, вышедший из-под pyinstaller, py2exe, cx_freeze, etc носит "клиентский" характер. А вам, как разработчику, нужен другой подход.

Comment: @Amaroc Пишите код в Linux, но тестом и деплоем занимайтесь в Windows. Да, в ней не так всё просто с установкой окружения, как в Linux, но если вы занялись разработкой под Windows, то от этого никуда не уйдешь ;) Потратьте время, настройте всё и пользуйтесь. Ну, либо прекратите писать под Windows.

Comment: @approximatenumber Мне нужно project.py и все используемые библиотеки в этом проекте запихнуть в один исполняемый файл exe, или файл .exe с .dll библиотеками (не знаю как правильно и должно быть). Если честно моя Ubuntu с Spider + Firefox + Chromium + Dragon, через пару часов просто виснет (подозрения на X-ы или плазму). Если сюда добавить виртуальную машину Windows, то вообще пожар будет. Просто нету смысла тогда программировать в Ubuntu а тестировать в Windows если все эти библиотеки заново надо будет ставить. Проще тогда один раз на Win все это поднять.

Comment: @Amaroc это уже другая история, сами понимаете. Из личного опыта: VirtualBox с дрессированной XP требует совсем немного ресурсов. Чтобы сделать один бинарный файл под Windows, нужна Windows. Тут придется смириться. )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это, должно помочь - [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/). Работает только под ОС Windows.

Данный метод только если используете Wine.
Для Linux используйте [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org).
Установите пакет для разработчиков, если отсутсвует:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Установите

```
Python PiP
apt-get -y install python-pip
```

Устанавливаем сам `Pyinstaller`

```
sudo pip install pyinstaller
```

Переходим в директорию где лежит наш проект.
и вводим

```
pyinstaller [имя файла]
```

> Без Wine, способ работал только в версии 1.4 - но к сожалению только на половину, не всегда проекты удавалось привести к работоспособности. Больше пока что информации нету.

Comment: @Insider спасибо! Поставил.  Выдает правда ошибку при попытке собрать (сократил там больше):

`$ build_exe lxml-v1.1-nopage.py 

    from . import _wapi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/py2exe/_wapi.py", line 4, in <module>


    _kernel32 = WinDLL("kernel32")
NameError: name 'WinDLL' is not defined`

Comment: @Amaroc я запутался в вашем вопросе изначальном, но теперь распутался :) `py2exe` не заработает под linux, вот он ошибку как раз выдает о том, что у него нет win-модулей (`winDLL`).

Comment: Спасибо!  Теперь когда распутались =), если вам известно другое решение - буду рад его увидеть. Думаю многим будет полезно если такое существует.

Comment: @Insider так а можете конкретнее сказать - PyInstaller позволяет на Linuxe, скомпилировать\упаковать все в один .exe файл для Windows - если да то как? Потому что следуя из документации на сайте - это отсутствует.

Comment: @Insider да установить то не проблема обе программы, проблема скомпилировать из под Linuxa в Windows без использования Wine

Comment: @Amaroc в версии 1.4 эта функция была, но работала только на половину. Сейчас требует пользоваться Wine.

Comment: @Amaroc кстати, вот нашел еще кое что, [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Разрабатывайте в Ubuntu, а для сборки/тестирования используйте виртуальную машину с Windows, например, как советовали выше. А лучше всего это дело автоматизировать, либо из IDE, либо с помощью самописных скриптов. Чтобы вы написали код, затем нажали кнопку, а на целевой системе всё собралось-запустилось.

Comment: Нет проблемы запустить скрипт под Windows и там собрать - проблема именно как в Ubuntu скомпилировать файл для Windows 7-8-10, не прибегая к wine\виртуальным машинам или перезахода в Windows среду с аналогичным набором библиотек\питона. Я бы и в Windows собрал но там придется убивать по 2-3-4 часа разбираясь как установить библиотеку lxml например которая требует Microsoft Compiler C++ v.10.

Comment: @Amaroc я вас понимаю, лично мне в Windows некомфортно заниматься python. Выше советовали `py2exe`, вроде он умеет. А вообще, можно бы было потратить пару часов на настройку виртуальной Windows, снять снапшот, и затем использовать ее постоянно в качестве образцового хоста. В данном случае, я думаю, всё является костылем, просто некоторые костыли посимпатичней.

Comment: Спасибо! На данный момент разбираюсь с py2exe - пока что примеры его использования есть только под Windows. Как пойму что делать и получу решение отпишу сюда.

Comment: Разве py2exe работает под Linux?

Comment: @Xyanight действительно оказывается не должно работать под линукс, хотя без проблем установилось.